# Is it true that some plants kill and eat animals?

Tags: outreach, animal-suffering

I had a discussion with some friends about vegetarianism, I explain to them that animals "suffer" during their slaughter, and some reasons that push me to be vegetarian ..

They were against, one of them gave me this strange "argument": "nature has made us the possibility to eat meat, besides, some plants kill animals to eat them"!

So, is it true?

Comment: Hi. I found this question in the Close queue with the reason being that it is unclear what you're asking. Now I personally think I understand what you are trying to ask but I don't see how that has anything to do with vegetarianism or other topics that this Q&A site is about. I think that in this case just typing into Google is a better option than asking question here beacuse it really is not a good fit. I vote to close.

Comment: I edited the title to be a question, rather than a statement. Hopefully I've captured the intent of what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Even if plants do eat animals, this isn't a very convincing argument for eating animals... I rarely model my behaviour on plants :)

Comment: "nature has made us the possibility to eat meat" This is the (unfortunately) common [naturalistic fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naturalistic_fallacy). Just because something is natural it doesn't mean that it is morally good or bad.

Comment: Well, many animals kill and eat other animals but i don't see that as a reason that I should.  I don't see that meat eating plants would be any more reason to do so.  Maybe, I won't eat those plants but the question has never come up.  However, I think that my mother just said that she is roasting a triffid for lunch.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you asking if [meat-eating plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnivorous_plant) exist?  They certainly do.  Would vegetarians or vegans [eat carnivorous plants](http://www.bbc.com/travel/story/20170502-where-people-eat-carnivorous-plants)?  That's a good question.  Probably not, because their cultivation would require exploiting animals (mostly insects).  They're quite rare, their consumption is even rarer, and I don't know if they're cultivated anywhere, so I don't think it's much of an issue in practice.

Answer (score 2):

The only plant I know of is the Venus fly trap. It eats anything that gets caught in its mouth such as flies, spiders, ants, any creature small that fits when it closes the mouth.

If you touch the inside of the plant's mouth/trap, it will produce the digestive enzymes then die. It will dissolve itself as it cannot stop the process once it starts.